# When exactly does Drippy use his "Tidy Tears" ability?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

It seems to normally occur when a hero loses consciousness and/or the our heroes' health is really low. Is it mentioned somewhere what the exact requirements are for Drippy to use his very useful albeit rare ability?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't taken a look at the code but here is what I think.

It's a low percentage chance when you have at least 1 down and the alive party members are at least 50% or below health.

Its basically done so you may have a fight saved. But it's not a certainty.